# Sort Map with Strings with accents with Collator

Tags: java, collections, groovy, collation

I'm trying to sort a map with Collator, by apparently it only works with lists

Im using this:

```
 import java.text.*

    Collator collator = Collator.getInstance()
    collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY)
    def list = [
  [name:"áaa", title:"foo1"],
  [name:"zzz", title:"foo2"],
  [name:"éee", title:"foo3"],
  [name:"ába", title:"foo4"],
  [name:"aaa", title:"foo5"] 
]

    Collections.sort(list.name, collator);

    ​list.collect{it.name}​
```

It returns `[áaa, zzz, éee, ába, aaa]`

but it should returns: `[áaa, aaa,ába,éee, zzz]`

How can i fix it? I need to keep the original map.
maybe I could use other class than Collator

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collections.sort` modifies the list `list.name`, which you are creating on the fly and not storing previously. It does get sorted, but the result is lost right after:

**Update**: added sorting without losing the map structure.

```
import java.text.*

def collator = Collator.instance
collator.strength = Collator.PRIMARY

def list = [
  [name:"áaa"],
  [name:"zzz"],
  [name:"éee"],
  [name:"ába"],
  [name:"aaa"] 
]

listc = list*.name

Collections.sort(listc, collator)

assert listc == ['áaa', 'aaa', 'ába', 'éee', 'zzz']


// Sorting without losing the map structure. 

sortedList = list.sort(false) { a, b -> collator.compare a.name, b.name }

assert sortedList == [
  [name:"áaa"],
  [name:"aaa"],
  [name:"ába"],
  [name:"éee"],
  [name:"zzz"],
]
```

Comment: Thanks! but how can I keep the original map? for example if is more complex
`def list = [
  [name:"áaa", title:"foo1"],
  [name:"zzz", title:"foo2"],
  [name:"éee", title:"foo3"],
  [name:"ába", title:"foo4"],
  [name:"aaa", title:"foo5"] 
]` 

I Need to sort the original Map